# MDL FAB button expand

Tags: jquery, html, css, material-design-lite

with something that is out of my area.

Basiclly I need a FAB button which morphs into a form so a new member can add a family member to their profile. for example say you have the following in your family.

- you
- Partner
- Kid 1
- Kid 2

Now since you have added your account, we need to add your partner (if they don't have an account) to do this we click the button with the + icon it expands to show a form with a user profile image (uplaod image - the + button then takes that image you uploaded and make puts that image in that circle and next to it a new + button is created with new ID)

Each time a user clicks on the + button it does the same form.

This is what I have done so far, note it does not have a separate form for each button.

My question is how do I turn this from what I have to auto create the new form and + button each time a + button is clicked?

https://codepen.io/russellharrower/pen/rzxLRj

html

```
<!-- on Morph FAB Display -->
<div class="fixed-action-btn">
  <div id="overlay" class="blue-grey hidden">  
    DEPENDING ON IF IT IS THE ADD BUTTON OR A IMAGE OF THEIR KID A DIFFENT FORM SHOULD SHOW.
  </div>
  <div class="btn-floating btn-large blue waves-effect waves-light">
    <img src="https://ipet.xyz/template/images/russellharrower.jpg"/>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-floating btn-large blue waves-effect waves-light">
    <i class="material-icons">
    add
  </i>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}

.fixed-action-btn {
  position:absolute;
  top:3%;
  left: 25%;
  right:25%;
  margin:0 auto !important;
  text-align:center;
  padding: 0;
  #overlay {
    position: absolute;
    text-align:center;
    transform-origin: center center;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    &.hidden {
      display:none;
      height: 55px;
      width: 55px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      transform: scale(1);
    }
    &.visible {
      // top: 0;
      // left: 20;
      // right: 0;
      // bottom: 0;
      height: 300px;
      color:#FFF;
      text-align:left;
      width: 300px;
      border-radius: 0;
      transform: scale(20);
    }
    h2 {
      position: fixed;
      transform: scale(1) !important;
      top: 100px;
    }
  }
}
#form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: none;
  // transform: translateY(200px);
  // display: none;
  z-index: 1000;
  transition: 0.5s ease;

  .btn-floating.red {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

JS

```
    $('.fixed-action-btn').click(function () {
  var morphFAB = $('#overlay');
  morphFAB.toggleClass('visible hidden');
  if (morphFAB.hasClass('visible')) {
    $('#form').addClass('animated slideInUp');
  }else {
    $('#form').removeClass('animated slideInUp');
  }
})
```

Comment: Having separate forms for each user is a really bad idea. Validating each will be a lot more difficult. You should have the same form and methods to link it's open/close animations to a particular element in the page as well as methods to reset or pre-populate it.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu yes it will all be the same form, but, the data for 1 kid needs to be sent to the server, and I ideally don't want to have to request that kids profile listing, if the mother or father clicks on. Do I store them in a array, or is there a better way?